# I want to change the background of a button on click

Tags: wpf, button, triggers, styles

I have two buttons, button1 and button2. Initially background of button1 will be white and button2 will be red.

When I click on button2, background of button2 should become white and button1 should become red. and if I click on button1 again, background of button1 should become white and button2 should become red in WPF.

To keep it short, it should work like a toggle button.

Comment: So why don't you use ToggleButton and style it properly?

Comment: Can you provide the code for what you have tried and explain the issue you're running into?

Answer (score 0):

A Code example would be nice , but here is an example how it could be done (without using mvvm)

here is my xaml:

```
    <StackPanel Width="300">
        <Button x:Name="button1" Background="White" Height="40" Click="button1_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="button2" Background="Red" Height="40" Click="button2_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

and here is the logic:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var temp = button1.Background;
            button1.Background = button2.Background;
            button2.Background = temp;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var temp = button2.Background;
            button2.Background = button1.Background;
            button1.Background = temp;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        changeBackground();
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        changeBackground();
    }

    private void changeBackground()
    {
        Button2.Background = Button2.Background == Brushes.Yellow ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Yellow;
        Button1.Background = Button1.Background == Brushes.Yellow ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Yellow;
    }
```